# prevent .hover event to trigger when page is reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

i have created a drop down for my notification tab and i use `.hover` event to trigger the drop down when mouse is on top of my notification tab.. but the problem i encounter is that `.hover` function runs when my page reloads. is there a way to prevent this from happening?

what i want to do is if the mouse hover the notification tab `.hover` will trigger.. this is the code i used.

```
$('li.nav-messages a:has("#nt_count")').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('span.badge').html(null);
  });
```

Comment: How come you don't use just CSS instead of jquery? It makes it so much easier. And already done for you.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Comment: i use .hover function to call the code inside of it..